# Using DB cursor in a web service pagination (Generate continuation token)

Tags: mongodb, web-services, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a service and evaluating various databases like Cassandra, MongoDB etc. One of the requirement is to do pagination. I see Cassandra doing auto-paging too.

Main question is how can I generate continuation token for service to use it? Is DB cursor short-lived or can it serve as continuation token?
/service_name?continuation_token=

Answer (score 2):

Specifically talking about Cassandra, the drivers automatically handle the paging for you. If the query returns a large result set and there are more "pages" to consume, you can just request the next page of results and keep requesting the next one until you've reached the end.

For example with the Java driver, you'll just make a call with the `fetchNextPage()` method to iterate over the results. For details, see [Paging with the Cassandra Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/paging/).

In case you weren't aware, the [Stargate.io](https://dtsx.io/2XHbiRo) data platform allows you to connect to your Cassandra cluster using RESTful, GraphQL + JSON/Document APIs. For example, adding a new record is as easy as sending a `POST` request to `/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/db_name/table_name/`. The Stargate APIs automatically save the page state and let's you easily page through the results so you might want to consider it for your web app.

If you wanted to try it out, we've got a free interactive tutorials on [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) like the [Stargate REST API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/rest). You can quickly build a proof-of-concept on [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) using the free tier (no credit card required) since Astra comes with Stargate bundled in so it's pre-configured and ready to use as soon as your database is ready.

As a side note, just like your [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383039/), this question is too broad and will likely get closed down by moderators.